# Analog circuit design/building resources for complete beginner

Tags: analog

I'm a 1st year mechatronic engineering student and am just starting out with analog electronics.  I have some projects coming up which will involve designing and drawing circuit diagrams to address particular problems and then building the circuits (e.g. a circuit for testing electronic components). Can you recommend some good books/web tutorials that would give an easy to follow, step by step guide to the process?

Comment: See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/whats-a-reference-text-on-analog-design?rq=1 and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/analog-circuit-design-resource-recommendations

Comment: Thanks pjc50 I came across those posts - I think the resources mentioned are for the more advanced, I'm a complete beginner! : ]

Answer (score 1):

A classic book, very well written, is *The Art of Electronics*, by Horowitz and Hill. Unfortunately, the current edition is getting pretty long in the tooth, and the parts described are not what a designer would likely choose in 2014. From his lair overlooking the Charles River, Win Hill has been working on a much-expanded 3rd edition (I've seen one chapter of it), but I'm not sure how imminent it is, and you might complete your undergraduate degree before it hits the shelves. The principles in AoE are sound, so it's well worth having a copy if you can score a used one. *Analog Circuit Design*, by the late Jim Williams is worth having. There are plenty of specialized books on things like SMPS design (Pressman and Billings' books), Electro-optical systems (the classic by Phil Hobbs) and so on.

You can learn a lot from on-line tutorials and application notes, but they don't always have the depth or accuracy you may need. Generally the *tutorials* from well-known companies are very well written, whereas some of the circuits shown in chip application suggestion are less practical. Anything from Linear Technology, Analog Devices, and much TI stuff can be very helpful.

Comment: e.g. linear technology application note 47, which is an extremely good textbook on op-amps hidden under an unassuming title.

Comment: Thanks a lot Spehro Pefhany I'll look into both of those books, and hopefully find some good online tutorials.